# Is ULS Viewer supported on SharePoint 2016?

Tags: sharepoint-server

Basically the title says it all:

is the use of ULSviewer supported on SharePoint 2016? (there does not seem to be a specific version of ULSviewer for SharePoint 2016)

Background Information:

ULS Viewer is a Windows application that provides a simplified view of ULS log files in SharePoint 2013 that supports aggregation, filtering, sorting, highlighting, append, and more.

Comment: Supported with 2016 as well as 2019.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most definitely so. I use the same one in SharePoint 2013 as in SharePoint 2016.

[Download ULS Viewer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44020)

Answer (score 1):

There is no new version of ULS viewer as the uls logs structure is the same across all the sharepoint versions.

So the latest version which released in 2013 is improved and supported tool for SharePoint 2016 as well.

> [**Download SharePoint ULS Viewer 2016**](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/uls-viewer-tool/)

Answer (score 0):

It works with SharePoint 2013, 2016 as well as 2019.

Comment: doesnt work for 2019,